# How do i unit test ExecuteReader()'s internal method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the below GetDocuments() method which is public, and i want to unit test the ReadData() method which is private. I am using Moq framework. what is the approach i have to take to test ReadData() using the GetDocuments() public method.

```
public IEnumerable<DocContent> GetDocuments(){
    sql = "testing"
    return sqlCommand.ExecuteReader<List<DocContent>>(sql, null, 
         (reader) => {
         while (reader.Read()) {
             contentDataList.Add(ReadData(reader));
         }
         return contentDataList;
    });
}


private DocContent ReadData(IDataReader reader) {
    return new DocContent() {
        Key = (string)reader["key"],
        Type = (string)reader["type"],
        ValueAsXmlDoc = ToXmlDocument((string)reader["value"])
    };
}
```

Comment: You wont be able to test `ReadData` directly because it is private. You will have to assert the result of the public member under test that are directly affected by the private member to infer expected behavior.

Comment: Just a thought, but if you used Dapper you'd have no need for either of these methods in the first place, since you could directly deserialize to an `IEnumerable<DocContent>`. Even better than testing code is eliminating it, especially boilerplate code like this.

Comment: It is impossible with constrained frameworks like Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy. You can mock only virtual members with their help. If you want mock non-virtual members you should use unconstrained tools such as TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes (all three are paid), or free alternatives: Prig, Ionad.Fody, AutoFake, Unmockable, Harmony, MethodRedirect, Pose, Shimmy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to test my methods with the help of my co-workers. Following is the code change i did to test my Implementation. First of all i had to Mock my DataReader. Then with the help of callback() i was able to trigger my internal private method.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetDocumentsShouldGetDocumentRecordsFromDB() {
        //Arrange
        var keys = new string[] {
            "Valid",
            "Invalid",
        };
        var types = new string[] {
            "Bookmarks",
            "Bookmarks",
        };
        var xmls = new string[] {
            "<Document><Regions></Regions></Document>",
            "<Document><Regions></Regions></Document",
        };

        var readerMock = CreateReaderMock(keys, types, xmls);

        string sqlCommand = null;
        IEnumerable<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = null;
        List<DocContent> docContents = null;

        sqlCommandMock
            .Setup(
                x => x.ExecuteReader(
                    It.IsAny<string>(),
                    It.IsAny<IEnumerable<SqlParameter>>(),
                    It.IsAny<Func<IDataReader, List<DocContent>>>()
                )
            )
            .Callback<string, IEnumerable<SqlParameter>,
            Func<IDataReader, List<DocContent>>>(
                (sql, parameters, readerFunction) => {
                    sqlCommand = sql;
                    sqlParameters = parameters;
                    docContents = readerFunction(readerMock.Object);
                }
            )
            .Returns(() => docContents);

        //Act
        var resultSharedDocContents = migrationDataAccess
            .GetDocuments();

        // Assert SQL command.
        // Verify Statements
    }

private Mock<IDataReader> CreateReaderMock(string[] keys,
            string[] types,
            string[] xmls) {
            var readerIndex = -1;

            var readerMock = new Mock<IDataReader>();
            readerMock
                .Setup(r => r.Read())
                .Returns(() => readerIndex < xmls.Length - 1)
                .Callback(() => readerIndex++);

            readerMock
                .Setup(r => r["key"])
                .Returns(() => keys[readerIndex]);

            readerMock
                .Setup(r => r["type"])
                .Returns(() => types[readerIndex]);

            readerMock
                .Setup(r => r["value"])
                .Returns(() => xmls[readerIndex]);

            return readerMock;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching unit testing this logic incorrectly - the public method signature is `IEnumerable<DocContent> GetDocuments` - and that's what should be tested. Unit testing does not approach testing specific *internals* of the class under test; only the public surfaces.

In your instance, it sounds like what you're doing is testing the sql response to translation logic - and you can actually do that entirely in an integration test.

1. You can construct a MDF file which is an in memory database of functionality using SQL Server syntax. You can easily add one from the Visual Studio Add Item menu.
2. You can populate that MDF file with content all with the SQL editor in Visual Studio.
3. At unit testing time, set your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to use the in memory MDF file. The connection string is like so:

   `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={DatabasePath};Database={databaseName};Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout={ConnectionTimeout}`
4. You can then invoke your public method signature and receive back fully hydrated objects that ran through your entire method chain, testing the `DocContent` objects you received back. It fully tests the integration between your code, the SQL driver, the SQL command you need to execute, and the translation of the objects coming back.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to move the `ReadData` method to the actual `DocContent` class and make it public (or use a constructor) - or have a separate class `DocContentFactory` with a public `ReadData` method and then unit test and use that.